# Passing ByteBuffer array from Java/Kotlin to C++/V8 results in incorrect data

Tags: java, c++, kotlin, v8

I'm trying to pass `byte[]` data from Kotlin to C++ to be passed to JavaScript via V8 ArrayBuffer.

In Kotlin:

```
val buffer = buffer.backingStore.asFloatBuffer()
val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffer.capacity() * 4)
byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(buffer)
```

The above works as expected and prints properly. The array is `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]`.

So `byteBuffer.array()` is passed through JNI to C++ is received as a `jbyteArray`. Here's where things get weird.

In C++, I try to convert it to `char` and pass it to a JavaScript function reference:

```
char* buffer = (char*) env->GetByteArrayElements(jbuffer, 0);
Local<ArrayBuffer> arrayBuffer = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(isolate_, length);
memcpy(arrayBuffer->GetContents().Data(), buffer, length);

Local<Value> argv[] = {
     arrayBuffer
};

v8::Local<v8::Context> ctx = hce->context_.Get(hce->isolate_);
v8::Function *fn = *(_bufferFn->Get(isolate_));
```

In JavaScript, I receive an ArrayBuffer with the correct length, but when I initialize a `Float32Array` from it, I get `[-428967904, -427919360, 4.175240064796526e-8]`.

I'm deep down the rabbit hole, way over my head here!

Comment: Did you print out the values on the C++ side as floats just to make sure it was passed correctly? How did you create the `Float32Array`? I have a feeling the issue here is actually `Endianness`.

Comment: The `Float32Array` was created in a [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) context and the lib exposes the `.backingStore.` from my code above.

I'll try to convert them to floats!

Comment: It is definitely endianness. Test: `Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(Float.floatToIntBits(1.1f))) == -428967904f`

Comment: where is `length` gotten/set?

Comment: I'm passing the length through the native JNI command `public void passBuffer(byte[] bytes) { PassBuffer(bytes, bytes.length); }` I did print that in C++ and it was correctly displaying as 12.

Comment: @Brandon The consensus is `Endianness` but somehow I'm even more lost :) If I cast to float in C++ `float floatbuffer[3]; std::copy(buffer,buffer+jlength,floatbuffer); LOGV("Float: %f", floatbuffer[0]);` It outputs 63.0. Another suggestion I received was to use `byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @michaeltheory; I'm not familiar with V8 so I can't write an answer even though I know what the problem is. I have a feeling v8 or Javascript itself might be using Little Endian.. Java and the JVM for sure uses BigEndian when reading and writing.. Try `byteBuffer = byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).slice();` and see if it fixes it. Perhaps your system is Big-Endian so the nativeOrder was the same. You should print your nativeOrder and order the buffer accordingly.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Do you want to post a solution so I can mark it as answered? It was as simple as adding `byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` before the `put`. I swear I tried that before, but *shrug*

Comment: I use Java.nio,Buffer all the time with c++ / NDK in android. I do not pass the buffer itself, just the memory address, which then is read with native access on either side. This is the most efficient data transfer of values, floats, doubles and anything else between the Java and C++